# Including TextMate grammars in VSIX packages

Tags: visual-studio-2019, syntax-highlighting, visual-studio-extensions

In an attempt to add basic Visual Studio editor support for MASM, following the guide *[Add a Language Server Protocol extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/adding-an-lsp-extension?view=vs-2019)*, I created a new VSIX project, added my colorization file under a directory named "Syntaxes", added the required *.pkgdef* file, and adjusted all the properties as specified in the tutorial, but no matter how I build the project, the colorization file does not work, even though it is included in the package.

When I copy it to *%USERPROFILE%.vs\Extensions\MASM\Syntaxes* folder, everything works as expected, but it's not a satisfactory solution, because I'd also like to add several new classification types and formats, and then map some of the scopes defined in *MASM.tmLanguage* to my new classifications using an additional *.tmTheme* file.

Here is the structure of my project:

[image: The structure of the project]

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ftug7sL-5kw) video shows how to add support for Julia, and it seems to work when they finally create a VSIX project, but, what's interesting, at the beginning of the video, they try placing their *Julia.tmLanguage* file in *%USERPROFILE%.vs\Extensions\Julia\Syntaxes*, and it doesn't work.

In my case, it's the other way around – the colorization file seems to be visible to Visual Studio only when I place it in the *.vs* folder in my home directory. Also, in the Assets section of my manifest file, there is a VsPackage asset linked to the entire project. I tried replacing it with one explicitly referencing my *.pkgdef* file, but it didn't solve the problem either. Am I missing something?

Comment: The screenshot is hardly readable. Can you [crop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cropping_(image)) it and otherwise make it minimum size?

Comment: Related: *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*).

Comment: @PeterMortensen, you can find a cropped version of the screenshot [here](https://ibb.co/JKwVLbq).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/troubleshooting-pkgdef-files/) guide on debugging *.pkgdef* files*, I was able to resolve the problem just by making sure that the base name of my *.pkgdef* file matches the unique product identifer specified in *source.extension.vsixmanifest*: make sure the *Product ID* field includes a valid GUID, and rename the *.pkgdef* file to *<Product ID>.pkgdef*, e.g. *Assembly_Language_Integration.D0775E55-5DAB-4D82-A47B-72DF63DA756E.pkgdef*.

*See *Issue: pkgdef File Is Not Found* and compare the names of the extensions installed in *$RootFolder$\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Community*, where *$RootFolder$* is the installation directory of Visual Studio.